# Google Cloud SDK: gcloud compute config-ssh crash

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud-cli

Running 'gcloud compute config-ssh' on a compute engine VM, I get the following error:

ERROR: gcloud crashed (UnicodeDecodeError): 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 1438: ordinal not in range(128)

My username & config directory do not contain non-English characters. Any suggestions?

Comment: I recommend using gcloud feedback and filing a bug against https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/list. A full stack trace would help.

Comment: Thank you Stephen, I've filed a bug as you suggested (https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=503). Not sure what you mean by a full stack trace.